# accept key word in <input type=''file" accept=''.zip'> opens file manager multiple times.

Tags: html

While trying to restrict file manager from displaying non require-able files formats. I figured out if one clicks the button multiple times the file manager opens multiple times, while it is not the case if you remove 'accept' attribute.

[refer](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish0019/69k1x5xp/1/)

```
 <input type="file" name="file"  accept='.zip'/>
 <input type="file" name="file1"/>
```

I want to know the reason why this happens not the work around.

Comment: Both of those `input`s behave the same for me in Chrome (minus the `accept`, of course); clicking them multiple times rapidly opens multiple successive dialogs. Can you clarify exactly what steps you have to take to notice a difference in behavior? What OS/browser are you using?

Comment: U add above html.
when u click first input element multiple times the pop up will appear multiple times even it is closed it it will open again and again..

but it is not the case for second input element

Comment: @qxz i used window 7 & and chrome 68.

Now with update chrome i dont face this issue any more.
Thanks